# How to close the bug on sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube

I have some doubts related on sonarqube. Anyone please help me..

First of all I want to know about snoarqube working flow. and I think the important part is quality profile, quality gates and issues management. 
I know about this we can create rule or deactivate rule by using quality profiles. please tell me some extra features that I want to learn..

> How to close the bug, how to limit the view for users
>
> If u assign some bugs to particular user, only the user can able to
>   see his/her bugs only.. then if the user fixes that bug, how you close
>   that bug etc..
>
> if I set it as fixed, then u check if its fixed then change the status
>   as closed ?

```
if the bug is fixed so how to close the bug or remove the bug ? 


but how ? I only changed the status to Fixed.. but the QA need to verify and close it   

when I change the status to Fixed the count in open bug reduced.. but it still not closed by QA   




Logging bug in sonarQube –
```

Comment: @Niels van Reijmersdal   Hai  please help me

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it is setup on your organization so i am just phrasing what we do in our organization:

Sonarqube is integrated with jenkin and scheduled it to run once a day, i.e. in the morning and after it's execution a report is generated which is emailed to the team members we want to know about the bugs, generally it consists of critical, major and minor bugs. Developers again work on those bugs starting from critical ones and fixes them and check in the code to svn. on the very next day we check the sonarqube reports again, and work on the latest reports.

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: if the bug is fixed so how to close the bug or remove the bug ?

Comment: it automatically decreases the number of bugs from report on next run.

Comment: but how ?  I only changed the status to Fixed.. but the QA need to verify and close it

Comment: when I change the status to Fixed the count in open bug reduced.. but it still not closed by QA

Comment: you are logging bug for that or integrated sonarqube with some bug logger?

Comment: Logging bug in sonarQube

Comment: In our case, its not logging any bugs, its just returning a report and removes the closed bugs by itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51228/discussion-between-antony-naveen-and-keshav).

Comment: I want to know is there any bug reporting functionality in sonarqube ?